# How to take an input parameter and make it return a float in C

Tags: c, int

I have an assignment where I have to write my own C Code that accepts one input parameter and gives a float as the out put. Currently I am stuck on making this happen. I've tried a lot of different ways of googling this but have come up with nothing.

My code allows a user to input how many burritos they wish to microwave and depending on what wattage they have they will be given a recommended amount of time to took it/them for in the microwave.

Here is what I have right now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int LowWatts(int burritos);
int MediumWatts(int burritos);
int HighWatts(int burritos);
int main ()
{

int burritos, menuSelect;
float Results;
burritos = (double)1; 


while (burritos > 0)
{
 printf ("Enter the amount of burritos you wish to cook \n: ");
 scanf("%d", &burritos);
 printf("%d\n", burritos);

 if (burritos > 0)
 {
 printf ("Enter 1 1100W, 2 to 1200W, 3 1250W microwave \n: ");
 scanf("%d", &menuSelect);
 printf("%d\n", menuSelect);
 if (menuSelect == 1)
 {
 Results = LowWatts(burritos);
 printf("For %d burrito(s) %.2f minutes is recomended for "
 "1100W microwave\n", burritos, Results);
 }
 else if (menuSelect == 2)
 {
 Results = MediumWatts(burritos);
 printf("For %d burrito(s) %.2f minutes is recomended for "
 "1200W microwave\n", burritos, Results);
 }
  else if (menuSelect == 3)
 {
 Results = HighWatts(burritos);
 printf("For %d burrito(s) %.2f minutes is recomended for "
 "1250W microwave\n", burritos, Results);
 }
 else
 printf("\nInvalid selection, please choose 1, 2, or 3 \n");
 } 
 } 
return 0;
}
int LowWatts(int burritos)
{
 return (double)(burritos*1.10);
} 

int MediumWatts(int burritos)
{
 return burritos*1.00;
}

int HighWatts(int burritos)
{
 return burritos*0.55;
}
```

Comment: What, googling "passing parameters to C" gives 0 results? `return (double)(burritos*1.10);` inside a function that returns an `int`? Nope. That's not right.

Comment: Did they teach you the difference between `int` and `double`?

Comment: John3163 I know trust me, DigitalNinja, what I am confused about is this: "Create your own function in C that accepts one input parameter and returns a float number." I'm just a little confused on what is meant by input parameter, am I to assume that I can have the code as double LowWatts(double burritos)?

Comment: @TByrd82 What is confusing then?

Comment: @narusin what is confusing is what is being asked of me, at this point. So, creating a parameter that accepts one input does that mean that this is a parameter: int LowWatt(int burritos) or is the parameter int burritos, menuSelect; ect?

Answer (score 2):

Your functions are all set to have a return type of `int`, so they will only return an `int`, no matter what kind of casting you do in the `return` statement.

Change them to return `float` or `double`.

Comment: Okay, so the only way to make this work would be to set the functions: int LowWatt(int burritos) ect to double or float. Would that be going against what is being asked here: "Create your own function in C that accepts one input parameter and returns a float number"

Comment: The assignment is explicitly telling you the function needs to return float. Since I doubt your professor has gone much into pass-by-reference, there is essentially only one way to do that: literally return a float (or double... be consistent in the code).